# RxJava: How to retry on next?

Tags: java, rx-java

I knew about:

- `retryWhen(...)` that allow us to retry on error
- and `repeatWhen(...)` that allow retrying on complete

Is there any operator like this:

```
    return Observable.just(isUpdating)
            .repeatWhenOnNext(isUpdating -> { 
                if(isUpdating) {
                    return Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // repeat after two seconds
                } else {
                    return Observable.just(isUpdating); // flow down to concatMap
                }
            })
            .concatMap(o -> doSomeWorkONLYWhenIsNotUpdating());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... No, but maybe this will do:

```
return Observable
    .interval(0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .filter(dummy -> !isUpdating)
    .take(1)
    .flatM(dummy -> doSomeWorkONLYWhenIsNotUpdating());
```